# How to make operations on rows that resulted from a self join query?

Tags: sql

I have a table containing many rows about financial data. Colums are as follows
Unixtime,open,high,low,close,timeframe,sourceId.

Given two assets with same timeframe but different sourceId, how to show a table which has
unixtime, Asset1open/asset2open,Asset1close/asset2close as columns?
Every resulting row should be the result of prices that have the same unixtime, and should be ordered by unixtime asc order.
How to do it with a self join?

Comment: Please read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention the specific database, so I'll assume this is for Sybase.

You can do:

```
select
  a.unixtime,
  a.open / b.open,
  a.close / b.close  
from t a
join t b on a.unixtime = b.unixtime and a.timeframe = b.timeframe
where a.sourceid = 123
  and b.sourceid = 456
order by a.unixtime
```